# pgfplots: legendentrys are wrong

Tags: pgfplots, legend

I'm using pgfplots to plot a lot of data as you can see below. For some of the plots I'v specified a legendentry, but the marks for these plots are not shown in the legend. does anyone know where the mistake is?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgflibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,arrows}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \centering
      \begin{axis}[
        height=10cm,
        width=\columnwidth,
        enlarge y limits=0.07,
        enlarge x limits=0.03,
        legend style={at={(0.5,-0.1)}, anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
        %ylabel={Bezugsphoneme: regspr. Vnt. (Hn)},
        symbolic x coords={a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w},
        xtick=data
        ]

        \addplot+[sharp plot, only marks, mark options={mark=-, scale=0.8, draw=black}] table[x=vpid, y=-] {data.dat};
        \addplot+[sharp plot, only marks, mark options={mark=-, scale=0.8, draw=black}] table[x=vpid, y=a] {data.dat};
        \addplot+[sharp plot, only marks, mark options={mark=-, scale=0.8, draw=black}] table[x=vpid, y=aa] {data.dat};
        \addplot+[sharp plot, only marks, mark options={mark=-, scale=0.8, draw=black}] table[x=vpid, y=ai] {data.dat};
        \addplot+[sharp plot, only marks, mark options={mark=-, scale=0.8, draw=black}] table[x=vpid, y=au] {data.dat};
        \addplot+[sharp plot, only marks, mark options={mark=-, scale=0.8, draw=black}] table[x=vpid, y=b] {data.dat};
        \addplot+[sharp plot, only marks, mark options={mark=o, scale=0.7, draw=black, solid}] table[x=vpid, y=c] {data.dat}; \addlegendentry{c}
        \addplot+[sharp plot, only marks, mark options={mark=-, scale=0.8, draw=black}] table[x=vpid, y=d] {data.dat};
        \addplot+[sharp plot, only marks, mark options={mark=triangle, scale=0.8, draw=black, solid}] table[x=vpid, y=ee] {data.dat}; \addlegendentry{ee}
        \addplot+[sharp plot, only marks, mark options={mark=-, scale=0.8, draw=black}] table[x=vpid, y=schwa] {data.dat};
        \addplot+[sharp plot, only marks, mark options={mark=-, scale=0.8, draw=black}] table[x=vpid, y=E] {data.dat};
        \addplot+[sharp plot, only marks, mark options={mark=-, scale=0.8, draw=black}] table[x=vpid, y=EE] {data.dat};
        \addplot+[sharp plot, only marks, mark options={mark=-, scale=0.8, draw=black}] table[x=vpid, y=f] {data.dat};
        \addplot+[sharp plot, only marks, mark options={mark=-, scale=0.8, draw=black}] table[x=vpid, y=g] {data.dat};
        \addplot+[sharp plot, only marks, mark options={mark=-, scale=0.8, draw=black}] table[x=vpid, y=ii] {data.dat};
        \addplot+[sharp plot, only marks, mark options={mark=-, scale=0.8, draw=black}] table[x=vpid, y=i] {data.dat};
        \addplot+[sharp plot, only marks, mark options={mark=-, scale=0.8, draw=black}] table[x=vpid, y=k] {data.dat};
        \addplot+[sharp plot, only marks, mark options={mark=-, scale=0.8, draw=black}] table[x=vpid, y=m] {data.dat};
        \addplot+[sharp plot, only marks, mark options={mark=-, scale=0.8, draw=black}] table[x=vpid, y=n] {data.dat};
        \addplot+[sharp plot, only marks, mark options={mark=-, scale=0.8, draw=black}] table[x=vpid, y=ng] {data.dat};
        \addplot+[sharp plot, only marks, mark options={mark=-, scale=0.8, draw=black}] table[x=vpid, y=oo] {data.dat};
        \addplot+[sharp plot, only marks, mark options={mark=-, scale=0.8, draw=black}] table[x=vpid, y=oe] {data.dat};
        \addplot+[sharp plot, only marks, mark options={mark=-, scale=0.8, draw=black}] table[x=vpid, y=oee] {data.dat};
        \addplot+[sharp plot, only marks, mark options={mark=-, scale=0.8, draw=black}] table[x=vpid, y=o] {data.dat};
        \addplot+[sharp plot, only marks, mark options={mark=-, scale=0.8, draw=black}] table[x=vpid, y=oi] {data.dat};
        \addplot+[sharp plot, only marks, mark options={mark=-, scale=0.8, draw=black}] table[x=vpid, y=p] {data.dat};
        \addplot+[sharp plot, only marks, mark options={mark=-, scale=0.8, draw=black}] table[x=vpid, y=pf] {data.dat};
        \addplot+[sharp plot, only marks, mark options={mark=square, scale=0.7, draw=black, solid}] table[x=vpid, y=r] {data.dat}; \addlegendentry{r}
        \addplot+[sharp plot, only marks, mark options={mark=diamond, scale=0.8, draw=black, solid}] table[x=vpid, y=s] {data.dat}; \addlegendentry{s}
        \addplot+[sharp plot, only marks, mark options={mark=pentagon, scale=0.8, draw=black,solid}] table[x=vpid, y=sch] {data.dat}; \addlegendentry{sch}
        \addplot+[sharp plot, only marks, mark options={mark=-, scale=0.8, draw=black}] table[x=vpid, y=t] {data.dat};
        \addplot+[sharp plot, only marks, mark options={mark=-, scale=0.8, draw=black}] table[x=vpid, y=ts] {data.dat};
        \addplot+[sharp plot, only marks, mark options={mark=-, scale=0.8, draw=black}] table[x=vpid, y=uu] {data.dat};
        \addplot+[sharp plot, only marks, mark options={mark=-, scale=0.8, draw=black}] table[x=vpid, y=u] {data.dat};
        \addplot+[sharp plot, only marks, mark options={mark=-, scale=0.8, draw=black}] table[x=vpid, y=v] {data.dat};
        \addplot+[sharp plot, only marks, mark options={mark=-, scale=0.8, draw=black}] table[x=vpid, y=uee] {data.dat};
        \addplot+[sharp plot, only marks, mark options={mark=-, scale=0.8, draw=black}] table[x=vpid, y=ue] {data.dat};
        \addplot+[sharp plot, only marks, mark options={mark=-, scale=0.8, draw=black}] table[x=vpid, y=z] {data.dat};
        \addplot+[sharp plot, only marks, mark options={mark=-, scale=0.8, draw=black}] table[x=vpid, y=sth_sch] {data.dat};    

        \addlegendimage{-}
        \addlegendentry{others}

      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

The data table:

```
vpid    -   a   aa  ai  au  b   c   d   ee  schwa   E   EE  f   g   ii  i   k   m   n   ng  oo  oe  oee o   oi  p   pf  r   s   sch t   ts  uu  u   v   uee ue  z   sth_sch
a   4   17  6   8   2   10  28  10  33  6   0   0   3   17  23  4   2   1   14  0   5   0   0   20  0   0   0   79  1   18  10  0   0   3   7   1   0   13  0
b   0   11  2   4   1   2   33  0   24  3   2   0   0   2   12  6   5   0   62  0   5   0   0   1   0   7   2   50  2   22  36  0   0   4   10  0   0   2   0
c   1   12  2   3   1   5   11  1   33  3   4   0   0   6   12  11  2   0   17  0   7   1   0   1   0   6   0   56  3   7   17  0   0   16  28  1   1   3   0
d   0   18  1   6   4   6   56  7   58  6   3   0   4   15  18  15  4   1   27  0   1   1   0   3   0   12  0   74  45  29  29  0   0   8   17  1   0   24  2
e   0   16  1   3   1   8   46  9   35  6   6   0   3   18  11  5   0   0   21  0   2   0   1   22  0   5   2   78  2   47  14  0   1   9   1   0   0   3   2
f   0   1   1   10  2   10  68  7   35  2   5   0   2   7   10  9   0   0   15  0   0   0   0   4   0   3   2   65  24  30  40  0   0   10  1   0   0   1   0
g   4   28  16  40  3   26  49  16  27  10  3   0   5   19  40  40  4   0   24  1   8   0   0   7   0   3   3   71  52  24  19  0   2   5   15  2   2   14  0
h   0   4   1   1   4   5   56  4   29  1   3   0   5   7   19  9   1   1   10  0   0   1   0   2   0   4   2   35  15  35  26  0   2   5   3   0   0   5   0
i   1   10  2   5   5   2   111 8   27  0   2   0   0   11  16  17  1   1   13  0   4   0   0   7   0   1   2   48  30  37  16  0   2   8   5   0   0   2   0
j   0   13  1   5   5   2   95  5   36  2   1   0   1   3   21  20  0   6   11  0   1   0   0   6   0   4   1   43  21  15  15  0   0   4   7   0   0   8   0
k   0   9   9   7   9   12  76  7   41  4   2   0   8   11  31  15  4   0   16  0   12  0   0   4   0   7   2   82  27  43  10  0   0   3   10  0   0   5   0
l   0   12  6   11  8   6   64  9   35  2   4   0   11  15  33  19  1   1   17  0   18  0   0   6   0   3   1   63  44  15  23  0   0   9   27  0   0   31  0
m   0   30  4   3   4   10  64  7   48  6   2   0   3   8   20  8   0   0   26  0   11  1   0   9   0   2   0   115 0   66  13  0   0   14  6   0   0   15  0
n   0   17  0   8   4   6   65  7   33  3   4   0   4   9   22  6   5   3   9   0   7   0   1   4   0   2   2   59  24  44  18  0   1   2   3   0   0   6   0
o   0   1   1   0   3   12  77  5   30  2   3   0   1   10  15  6   0   0   7   0   2   0   0   1   0   4   0   51  0   45  21  0   1   5   3   1   0   2   0
p   0   28  4   6   5   6   41  8   38  1   0   0   2   4   43  3   1   0   17  0   3   0   0   4   0   4   0   65  2   35  26  0   1   2   21  0   0   3   3
q   0   14  3   4   6   2   60  2   30  2   3   0   6   13  29  2   0   1   9   0   3   0   0   3   0   4   2   66  0   38  10  0   0   6   14  0   0   8   0
r   0   40  7   5   5   5   109 13  43  3   2   0   5   17  30  25  1   1   14  0   3   0   0   13  0   4   0   74  71  32  22  0   6   2   22  0   0   4   0
s   1   12  1   2   2   17  41  14  26  2   0   0   3   18  22  5   0   0   11  0   3   0   0   7   0   1   1   62  4   41  8   0   2   4   1   0   0   6   1
t   6   81  44  16  6   20  111 23  31  29  6   0   3   34  70  61  3   0   8   0   24  0   0   13  3   6   3   95  102 52  56  0   18  5   35  6   1   8   0
u   0   19  5   4   17  15  114 22  38  2   8   0   5   8   24  16  1   0   10  0   13  0   0   7   0   2   0   82  25  61  25  0   0   0   11  0   0   13  0
v   0   25  7   6   11  20  142 7   21  6   4   0   7   21  45  15  3   1   12  0   13  0   0   5   0   0   0   52  24  23  37  0   2   6   11  0   0   16  0
w   0   24  1   6   14  6   74  14  15  3   3   0   11  12  22  2   5   1   3   0   7   0   0   6   0   2   0   46  0   35  17  0   1   2   8   0   0   14  0
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of reordering the plots, you can also supply `forget plot` to those series that will not get an entry in the legend.

For complicated plots like yours, it's best to work with styles. I've adjusted your example a bit:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgflibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \centering
      \begin{axis}[
        height=10cm,
        width=\columnwidth,
        enlarge y limits={upper, value=0.07},
        enlarge x limits=0.03,
        legend style={
            at={(0.5,-0.1)}, 
            anchor=north, %Proper alignment
            nodes={anchor=mid},
            legend columns=-1,
            /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=4pt} %Increase spacing in legend
        },
        symbolic x coords={a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w},
        xtick=data,
        xticklabel style={text height=1.5ex}, % To get proper alignment
        only marks,
        every axis plot post/.style={draw=black}, %Common options
        other/.style={
            forget plot,
            mark options={
                mark=-, scale=0.8
            }
        },
        c plot/.style={
            mark options={mark=o, scale=0.7, solid}
        },
        ee plot/.style={
            mark options={mark=triangle, scale=0.8, solid}
        },
        r plot/.style={
            mark options={mark=square, scale=0.7, solid}
        },
        s plot/.style={
            mark options={mark=diamond, scale=0.8, solid}
        },
        sch plot/.style={
            mark options={mark=pentagon, scale=0.8,solid}
        }
]

        \addplot [other] table[x=vpid, y=-] {data.dat};
        \addplot [other] table[x=vpid, y=a] {data.dat};
        \addplot [other] table[x=vpid, y=aa] {data.dat};
        \addplot [other] table[x=vpid, y=ai] {data.dat};
        \addplot [other] table[x=vpid, y=au] {data.dat};
        \addplot [other] table[x=vpid, y=b] {data.dat};
        \addplot [c plot] table[x=vpid, y=c] {data.dat}; \addlegendentry{c}
        \addplot [other] table[x=vpid, y=d] {data.dat};
        \addplot [ee plot] table[x=vpid, y=ee] {data.dat}; \addlegendentry{ee}
        \addplot [other] table[x=vpid, y=schwa] {data.dat};
        \addplot [other] table[x=vpid, y=E] {data.dat};
        \addplot [other] table[x=vpid, y=EE] {data.dat};
        \addplot [other] table[x=vpid, y=f] {data.dat};
        \addplot [other] table[x=vpid, y=g] {data.dat};
        \addplot [other] table[x=vpid, y=ii] {data.dat};
        \addplot [other] table[x=vpid, y=i] {data.dat};
        \addplot [other] table[x=vpid, y=k] {data.dat};
        \addplot [other] table[x=vpid, y=m] {data.dat};
        \addplot [other] table[x=vpid, y=n] {data.dat};
        \addplot [other] table[x=vpid, y=ng] {data.dat};
        \addplot [other] table[x=vpid, y=oo] {data.dat};
        \addplot [other] table[x=vpid, y=oe] {data.dat};
        \addplot [other] table[x=vpid, y=oee] {data.dat};
        \addplot [other] table[x=vpid, y=o] {data.dat};
        \addplot [other] table[x=vpid, y=oi] {data.dat};
        \addplot [other] table[x=vpid, y=p] {data.dat};
        \addplot [other] table[x=vpid, y=pf] {data.dat};
        \addplot [r plot] table[x=vpid, y=r] {data.dat}; \addlegendentry{r}
        \addplot [s plot] table[x=vpid, y=s] {data.dat}; \addlegendentry{s}
        \addplot [sch plot] table[x=vpid, y=sch] {data.dat}; \addlegendentry{sch}
        \addplot [other] table[x=vpid, y=t] {data.dat};
        \addplot [other] table[x=vpid, y=ts] {data.dat};
        \addplot [other] table[x=vpid, y=uu] {data.dat};
        \addplot [other] table[x=vpid, y=u] {data.dat};
        \addplot [other] table[x=vpid, y=v] {data.dat};
        \addplot [other] table[x=vpid, y=uee] {data.dat};
        \addplot [other] table[x=vpid, y=ue] {data.dat};
        \addplot [other] table[x=vpid, y=z] {data.dat};
        \addplot [other] table[x=vpid, y=sth_sch] {data.dat};    

        \addlegendimage{other}
        \addlegendentry{others}

      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Jake! Thanks again for your really nice work, I'm learning a lot from your examples. I had migrated the styles to my original plot, but now I the effect of \addlegendimage{other} is nothing. The "other"-style is not plotted in the legend. Do you have some ideas on that?

Comment: Glad it helps! Hm, not sure about the missing entry for `other`. Probably best to post a new question with an example.

Comment: I tried Jake's example and the entry for `other` is present and seems to be ok.... are you sure you added both `\addlegendimage` and `\addlegendentry`?

Answer (score 5):

That is because `\addlegendentry` makes a list which is constructed from the number of calls to that command.
This means that the first call to `\addlegendentry` applies to the first `\addplot`, the second call of `\addlegendentry` applies to the second `\addplot`. No matter the location of the command itself.
What you need to do is assemble all your `\addplot`s to the `\addlegendentry` calls.

Effectively:

```
\begin{axis}
\addplot+[sharp plot, only marks, mark options={mark=o, scale=0.7, draw=black, solid}] table[x=vpid, y=c] {data.dat}; \addlegendentry{c}
\addplot+[sharp plot, only marks, mark options={mark=triangle, scale=0.8, draw=black, solid}] table[x=vpid, y=ee] {data.dat}; \addlegendentry{ee}
\addplot+[sharp plot, only marks, mark options={mark=square, scale=0.7, draw=black, solid}] table[x=vpid, y=r] {data.dat}; \addlegendentry{r}
\addplot+[sharp plot, only marks, mark options={mark=diamond, scale=0.8, draw=black, solid}] table[x=vpid, y=s] {data.dat}; \addlegendentry{s}
\addplot+[sharp plot, only marks, mark options={mark=pentagon, scale=0.8, draw=black,solid}] table[x=vpid, y=sch] {data.dat}; \addlegendentry{sch}
....
<other>
\end{axis}
```